# Как лучше спроектировать БД?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть 2 типа пользователей и у каждого примерно 11 видов форм обратной связи (у каждого типа свои поля), в каждой 15-30 полей и многие поля в которых одинаковы (от 50% до 70%). Как лучше ее спроектировать? и соответственно как потом лучше вынимать данные, например если нужно вывести все формы заполненные конкретным пользователем?

Comment: Разреженная таблица (в полях, которых нет в форме - Null).

Comment: А в какие еще могут быть варианты? и в каком случае стоило бы использовать отдельные таблицы для разных форм?

Comment: *какие еще могут быть варианты?* EAV. Сериализация (XML, JSON). *в каком случае стоило бы использовать отдельные таблицы для разных форм* Да почти ни в каком. Появление новой формы потребует из кода клиента изменять структуру БД, что в общем случае не поощряется.

Comment: Спасибо! Пойду пожалуй читать теорию :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать БД с поддержкой наследования таблиц. Я использую для этого postgresql.

Допустим, есть абстрактная сущность - user_form. В этой сущности можно описать все поля, которые будут общими у всех сущностей.

```
CREATE TABLE user_form
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  type character varying NOT NULL,
  field1 character varying,
  --.....
  CONSTRAINT user_form_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

Далее сущность user_admin_form

```
CREATE TABLE user_admin_form
(
-- Унаследована from table user_form:  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_form_id_seq'::regclass),
-- Унаследована from table user_form:  type character varying NOT NULL,
-- Унаследована from table user_form:  field1 character varying,
  field2 character varying,
  CONSTRAINT user_admin_form_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
) INHERITS (user_form);
```

По аналогии можно создавать и другие дочерние таблицы. Обязательно используйте указатель типа записи для того, что бы определить, в какой таблице она находится, потому что все записи будут доступны в родительской таблице.